# Is this cohomology isomorphic to De Rham Cohomology?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, homology-cohomology, smooth-manifolds

Let $(M,g)$  be  a  Riemannian  manifold. Put $d^{*}= *d*$  where $*$ is the  Hodge $*$ operator. So $d^{*}\circ d^{*}=0$. Then it introduce  a (c0)homology.

> What is  a relation between this  (co)homology  and  De Rham cohomology? Are They isomorphic?

Comment: Yes, of course; the Hodge star is invertible and you're essentially conjugating by it. A more interesting idea along these lines is given by Hodge theory.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks for your comment.